# Can you create a generic or fake swiping motion/touch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is there a way to create a simulated or fake swiping motion? I want to press a button, that launches a simulated touch on the screen, moving an object.

For context, I programmed a tinder kind of swiping with a stack of images. Now I am trying to add a button to swipe them right, and a button to swipe them left.

This was all for learning purposes, I didnt program the swiping functionality originally with the buttons in mind.

This is all in react native btw.'

Thank you guys for any insight at all!

Comment: Check this https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/handler-fling/

Comment: I will look into it when I am done with class for the day! Thanks for taking the time to try and help me out!